# Retrieving images from Django from rest_framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

## models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
class Photo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    file = models.FileField()
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

## serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from . models import Photo

class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields='__all__'
```

## views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views import View
import time
from rest_framework import generics
from .forms import PhotoForm
from .models import Photo
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework import status
from .serializers import imageSerializer 
import requests       


class DragAndDropUploadView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        photos_list = Photo.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'UploadMulti/drag_and_drop_upload/index.html', {'photos': photos_list})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PhotoForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': photo.file.name, 'url': photo.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)


def clear_database(request):
    for photo in Photo.objects.all():
        photo.file.delete()
        photo.delete()
    return redirect(request.POST.get('next'))



class ImagesList(APIView):
    def get(self,request):
        imagelist=Photo.objects.all()
        serializer = imageSerializer(imagelist,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data) 
    def post(self):
        pass    

def backend(request):
    response = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/images/')
    api_values = response.json()
    for values in api_values:
        print(type(values['file']))
    return render(request,"home.html",{'data':api_values})
```

**when I print type of values.file which is the image data I am getting as  therefore when sending it to frontend the image is not displayed**

*How to retrieve as image file from rest api?*

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "",
        "file": "think-twice-code-once.jpg",
        "uploaded_at": "2019-11-27T12:34:32.270786Z"
    }
]
```

Is there any other method to obtain images from rest framework and whether the image is stored as Image format ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to your configuration of [`FileField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#filefield) for this particular serializer. You need `use_url` to be True. So you can either change the `UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL` setting or set `use_url=True` in `imageSerializer` as seen below.

```
class imageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
        fields='__all__'
    file = serializers.FileField(use_url=True)
```

Side note, `imageSerializer` should really be `ImageSerializer` to follow the python class naming guidelines.